# Nonlinear mathematical modeling using differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\dot{N_1}=r_1N_1\left(1 - \frac{N_1}{K+b_{12}N_2}\right)\\
\dot{N_2}=r_2N_2\left(1 - \frac{N_2}{K+b_{21}N_1}\right)
\end{array} \right. $$
I would like to ask you, how could I interpret this model?
How about symbiosis process? I think it is could be something like symbiosis process, because as we could see we have two competing populations.
the biggest problem i have with understanding dividing by $N_1$ and $N_2$.

There is only one assumption: all parametres are nonnegative.

Comment: Please provide more details about what $N_1, N_2, r_1, r_2, K$ etc are. This is not enough information.

Comment: I know that all parameters are nonnegative. My teacher had nothing more to say about that. I think that this could be a two dimensional modification of lotka volterra model. But I do not know how could I describe them.